# Rotating a sprite to follow a mouse point?

Tags: flash, rotation, mouse, point, haxe

I am designing a game in Haxe NME using Flashdevelop. I have an object on the screen and I want it to rotate to follow the mouse as the mouse moves. I have the object rotating at the same speed as the mouse, but it doesn't point towards the mouse. It's like there is a phantom mouse on the screen that moves whenever my mouse moves.

This is the code that gets called whenever the mouse changes positon:

```
public function mouseProcess(e:MouseEvent) 
{
    var Xdistance:Float = e.localX - survivor.x;
    var Ydistance:Float = e.localY - survivor.y;
    survivor.rotation = Math.atan2(Ydistance, Xdistance) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

`e.localX/Y` gets the current x,y position of the mouse and the survivor. x/y gets the x,y position of the object that needs to rotate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything wrong with your method.  I used it (almost) verbatim with the following code to set up a sprite that tracks the mouse as I move it.  Perhaps take a look at what I've written and see if it differs to the code you have.  Failing that, perhaps post more of what you've done?

```
// Creates the sprite that will visually track the mouse.
private function CreateSurvivor() : Sprite
{
    // Create a green square with a white "turret".
    var shape = new Shape();
    shape.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);        
    shape.graphics.drawRect(50, 45, 50, 10);
    shape.graphics.endFill();

    // Center the square within its outer container.  Allows it to spin 
    // around its center point.
    shape.x = -50;
    shape.y = -50;

    var survivor = new Sprite();
    survivor.addChild(shape);

    return survivor;
}
```

The init method just creates the survivor and attaches it to the display list.

```
private function init(e) 
{
    m_survivor = CreateSurvivor();
    m_survivor.x = 300;
    m_survivor.y = 200;

    addChild(m_survivor);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseProcess);
}
```

And finally, your original method:

```
public function mouseProcess(e:MouseEvent) : Void
{
    var Xdistance:Float = e.localX - m_survivor.x;
    var Ydistance:Float = e.localY - m_survivor.y;
    m_survivor.rotation = Math.atan2(Ydistance, Xdistance) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is different in NME, but Flash's `Math.atan2()` gives a value which starts from 0 pointing to the left (negative x), whereas display objects start with 0 pointing up, so does simply adding `+ 90` to your angle help?

Comment: That fixed it. I knew it was probably something simple I was missing.